# Zend Studio for Eclispse Expand All feature

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

is there a way to select a folder and somehow expand all the child folders of the selected folder? It would be very useful.

The issue that I imagine is that because in Zend Studio php files are expandable also so they can show their classes namespaces methods and etc if there is a way to expand a folder and all its subfolders it shouldn't expand php files too.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would like to know if there is a general answer for expanding all the subfolders in the project explorer (I'm using Eclipse CDT).

Answer (score 0):

In the project view, this feature does not exists.

However, you can right click on your top folder then click "search". This will open a search window. Simply press the "search" button without any search field entered and another window will appear with the results. In this window, you have a small "expand all" button in the top corner.

You can also right click on your top folder in that window and the "expand all" option will be displayed there too.